# Scala Variables scope

Tags: scala

I have created a simple method which is returning a Date value.
Before processing the method "convertStrToDate" i want to do a null check condition. So that if it is not null then i want to process the method.
The problem am facing is that the scope of the variable returnvar is with in the "If loop". So i could not use the variable "returnvar" outside the if loop where i actually need to return as a output to the method.
Can anyone please help to fix this.

```
def convertStrToDate(inputvar: String): Date = {
  if (inputvar != null && inputvar.nonEmpty) {
    val format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat(inputvar)
    val formattedvar: Date = format.parse(inputvar)
    var returnvar = new java.sql.Date(formattedvar.getTime());
  }
return returnvar
}
```

Comment: put  return in if

Comment: What do you return in case the input is null or empty?

Comment: i want to return null actually

Comment: if i add the below change am not getting any syntax error

if{…
…
...
return returnvar
}
else {
 return null
}

But am getting null pointer exception after submitting the Job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Option` for this purpose.

If your computation is successful return `Some(value)` or else return `None`

Notice that return type of method is changed to `Option[Date]`

```
  def convertStrToDate(inputvar: String): Option[Date] = {
      if (inputvar != null && inputvar.nonEmpty) {
        val format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat(inputvar)
        val formattedvar: Date = format.parse(inputvar)
        var returnvar = new java.sql.Date(formattedvar.getTime())
        Some(returnVar)
      } else None
    }
```

Note that `return` is optional in scala

**The idiomatic way.**

Get `Some(input)` if inputvar is valid and then map to produce subsequent values.

```
def convertStrToDate(inputvar: String): Option[Date] = { 
   Option(inputvar).filter(_.nonEmpty).map { inputStr =>
     val format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat(inputStr)
     val formattedvar: Date = format.parse(inputStr)
     new java.sql.Date(formattedvar.getTime())      
   }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou.... its working... If i use Option[Date] as return type and returning as Some(returnvar) or also as Option(returnvar).

Comment: I actually initiated this question for the issue of the scope of the variables with in the method with which i could not add the if(null check) condition and finally fixed the return var issue(Datetype)  as per above conversation. Thanks

Comment: I think it would be more idiomatic to first convert the `inputvar` into an `Option` then use `map`.

Comment: @Reactormonk thanks for the suggestion .. edited the answer

Comment: Taking a second look, `Some(inputvar).filter(_.nonEmpty).map { inputStr =>` might be an even better approach.

Comment: @Reactormonk   inputvar can be null

Comment: Ehh, `Option(inputvar)`.

Comment: @Reactormonk edited the answer. thanks for the suggestion

Comment: If i had to define method in the similar way but if the return type is Long.

Comment: I mean if i want to convert String to Long.

Comment: def convertStrToDate(inputvar: String): Long = {
        if (inputvar != null && inputvar.nonEmpty) {
          var y = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
          var z: Date = y.parse(inputvar);
          var l: Long = z.getTime();
        Some(l)
      } else None
    }

Comment: Option(str).map(_.toLong)

Comment: The input variable that am passing to the method is String of Date like "2015-07-01".                                                                                                             So i have to format it first and then try to convert to Long.                          var a = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
      var b: Date = a.parse(inputvar);
      var c: Long = b.getTime();

Comment: If i had to define a method, i think the same way i can use the return type as "Option[Long]" and return "Some(longvar)" under if condition and "None" under else condition